# am-yisrael-jewish-nation tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [am-yisrael-jewish-nation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am-yisrael-jewish-nation) tag currently is applied to ten questions.

Four or five of these are about the state of being a Jew:

- [When did Avraham Avinu become Jewish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8646)
- [Can a Jew lose their Jewish Status?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7775)
- [Is it possible for a Gentile to convert to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7210)
- [Matrilineal Descent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6704)
- sort of [Image of God: Equality and Discrimination](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/185)

Three are about Jews:

- [Comedy and Jewish Life](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8950) — about Jews as contrasted with others
- [Is one obligated to believe a fellow jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7840) — about one's claiming to be a Jew
- [Purchasing from a Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6271) — about Jews as contrasted with others
- sort of [Image of God: Equality and Discrimination](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/185)

And the remaining two are about what Judaism is or entails:

- [Why is Judaism not Racism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7792)
- [Difference between jewish and zionist?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7772)

Probably the tag should be split into several, or some questions retagged (or both). Ideas?

Comment: The last two are specifically about the nationalist aspect of Judaism.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, sort of. The Zionism question asker deemed _Judaism_ as referring specifically to the religion, and contrasted that with Zionism. The question then asked, essentially, whether that was correct or there was another sense of _Judaism_ some might use. So the question was about three things: Judaism the religion, Zionism, and _Judaism_ the term.

Comment: msh210, The Zionism aspect of that question is specifically about the nationalist aspect of Judaism, so the question is not a generic Judaism question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, right, okay.